# How to delete artifacts from Kubeflow?

Tags: minio, artifact, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

Kubeflow pipeline runs generate artifacts, which from what i can see in the dashboard are saved on minio. How can I delete them? [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it can be done through minio UI. To access minio remotly use configured `kubectl`:

`kubectl port-forward -n kubeflow svc/minio-service 9000:9000`

And then in web browser go to `localhost:9000`.

Also each bucket can be assigned a lifecycle rule, which will give objects added under some prefix expiration date
https://docs.min.io/docs/python-client-api-reference.html.

Comment: Access key and Secret key are required when I get access to localhost:9000. How do you get them?

Comment: I found:minio, minio123

Comment: This will remove the artifact files. However, the artifacts are still listed on the Kubeflow dashboard "Artifacts". Any idea how to remove those entries for which the MinIO data was deleted?